# Does NgRx store's select operator return a behavioursubject?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Whenever we subscribe to `this.store.select('')`, we immediately get the current state of the store slice. Since, even though no value was emitted for sometime when this subscription happened, can we conclude that select is a behaviourSubject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.store.select('')` is a Observable.
[`State`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/state.ts) is a `BehaviorSubject` though, that's why you get the current state.

Comment: Right, understood, thank you.